# Login using MFA using JMeter

Tags: blazemeter, jmeter-5.0

So i am trying to login to my application through Jmeter , it requires MFA , and so it returns the token in a variable in the response header "
i used blazemeter to record the login procedures it got , then i added a listener , reg expression and a JSR Post processor

I am giving the the thread only 1 user , however i am getting a lot of trials in the summary tree log , also its not getting the token and logging in , any help please ? , i attached my jmeter shots

I want to en-pose the login and the token to successfully login to the application[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XRqg.png)

```html
1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:187) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
 at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:925) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:564) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script9.groovy: 1: unexpected token:  @ line 1, column 63.
   *****"+vars.get(" AUTH-TOKEN")
```

Comment: There is an exception in log, seen partial in image. add full exception(s) to question

Comment: @user7294900 HYG